# onclick not working if function is nested within another function

Tags: javascript, html

On my page I have had a series of onclick events which have always worked fine when the associated javascript function is included within the script section of that web page.

I have since bundled up my javascript into a separate file held within a separate scripts folder.  All javascript required for the page is called via this script file via a function in the script section.  This works for all javascript requirements on the page except for the onclick function.

If I place the function I require at the 'top level' of this js file, the onclick function will work.  However, If I place it within another function (i.e. the function called for all javascript on that page) it does not work.

Does this mean the onclick event can't 'read' functions nested within other functions?

Comment: Yes it does. Code in `onEVENT` attributes is executed in the global scope.

Comment: Stop using inline attributes and learn to use things like `addEventListener`.

Comment: Hi @Barmar, many thanks for your response.  I have updated my code with `addEventListener` 's and it is now working a treat.  Thanks again!